# jQuery selector efficiency

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors, memory-efficient

I have a quick Bing and can't really find the answer.

If I have a whack of code that uses `$('something here')` 150 times, would it be more efficient to:

```
var item = $('something here')
```

Pretty silly questions I know, but would it be more efficent as jQuery only has to find the item once?

Comment: Why not run a test at http://jsperf.com/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, storing the resulting jQuery object is tremendously more efficient and may be magnitudes faster. Each time you use a selector you are initiating a new search. jQuery does not cache results. If you store the resulting jQuery object in a variable, you are effectively eliminating the need to run the search over and over again each time.

Comment: True (+1), however, this should be annotated with "it doesn't always matter" and "run some performance tests". Write clean code first (which I find normally does *not* have repeat selectors).

Comment: The search is usually negligible. It's the creation of the large jQuery object every time that's the real slow down.

Comment: Depends on what the search is for - some selectors are really cheap, some are expensive (esp. if the browser can't do it natively)

Answer (score 4):

According to this article, it is more efficient to assign the selector to a variable, which makes sense since jQuery does not need to scan the DOM for elements matching the selector again.

http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/07/14/jquery-selector-efficiencycost-impact.aspx

It also provides other tips. For instance, try to avoid using the class selector alone. Interestingly, a selector such as `$('#someID')` is faster than `$('div#someID')`.

Comment: `$("#someID")` maps to the native function `getElementById()`, that is why it is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this article to know exactly how jQuery is working behind the screen.
Very well explained.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-jquery-newbs-stop-jumping-in-the-pool/